# FIM execute script doesn't work

Tags: bash, timer, imageview, raspberry-pi

I work with a raspberry pi dabian weezy. i need help whit FIM

if in a bash i put:

```
fim -E mySHcode.sh img.jpg
```

I expecting with this that fim execute before mySHcode, and after view img.jpg. but only I can see the image.

When i execute it, I can see the img.jpg in my screen, but the script `mySHcode.sh` doesn't work!
I only need to show the only one image 10 seconds (like a splashscreen)... there are some that work as timer?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To make a splash screen how about this:

```
#/bin/bash
fim img.jpg &
child_pid=$!
sleep 5
kill $child_pid
clear
```

It runs fim in the background, then kills it 5 seconds later and clears the screen.